# get a list of user likes

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I have about 5 - 25 like url's on my page , I want to be able to find out if the user has already liked one.  Right now I am doing something like

```
foreach ( like url){
 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/@id?access_token=
}
```

that's obviously not real code , but you get the point , this works fine , but I am making sometimes 30 api calls per user per page load just from this loop.  that's bad.  We're starting to hit the api limit and getting blocked from facebook- also bad.

I want a way to pass an array of id's and see which ones the user has liked, I was thinking maybe through fql ?? I thought up this , doesn't seem to be working though

```
'SELECT post_id FROM like WHERE user_id = ' + me ' AND object_id IN ( ' + arrayOfIds + ' )'
```

Comment: should work, can you show the generated query / result? perhaps you don't have read_stream permissions?

Comment: @Guy - the result was an empty array, I would think I would be getting an error if I didn't have permission

Comment: @Guy - oh I should mention, the id is comming from what would normally be <fb:like href="facebook.com/pages/[pagename]/[id]   is that last part of the url the object_id or post_id ??

Comment: I believe it's the post_id